# Buttons in iCarousel not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, icarousel

I have set the buttons programmatically as below:-

```
-(UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view

{

    UILabel *label = nil;
    DoctorInfo *docInfo = self.allDoctorInfo[index];




    //create new view if no view is available for recycling

    if (view == nil)

    {

        //don’t do anything specific to the index within

        //this `if (view == nil) {…}` statement because the view will be

        //recycled and used with other index values later
        view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 200.0f)];
        CGFloat centerPoint = (view.frame.size.width / 2) - 25;

        ((UIImageView *)view).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"card_shadowed.png"];
        view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        UIImageView *headImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(centerPoint, -30, 50, 50)];
        headImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"face.png"];
        [view addSubview:headImage];


        //share button
        UIButton *shareButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, -40, 20, 20)];
        [shareButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"share_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [shareButton addTarget:self action:@selector(shareSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [shareButton.superview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        shareButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [view addSubview:shareButton];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:shareButton];

     return view;
}
```

And in viewdidload:-

```
 self.carousel.delegate = self;
   self.carousel.dataSource = self;
    self.carousel.type = iCarouselTypeTimeMachine;
    self.carousel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

I have tried all the suggestions that I googled but none is working in my case. How can I make the button clickable inside iCarousel ?

Comment: You haven't set `userInteractionEnabled` to true in your carousel `view`s

Comment: i have tried adding view.userInteractionEnabled = YES inside viewforitematindex but its still not working @Paulw11

Comment: You should try to add the button outside of the `if(view == nil)` block just before you return the view.

Comment: You can refer this ans by @Nick himself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22145978/my-custom-button-is-not-getting-click-in-icarousel-ios

Answer (score 1):

its working perfect try this code

```
    func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    var itemView = UIImageView()
    itemView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 0, width: carousel.frame.size.width - 60, height: 220 ))
    itemView.image = UIImage(named: imagesArray[index])

    itemView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    itemView.setCornerRadius(clipToBounds: true, radius: 10)
    //itemView.setBorder(color: .red, width: 2)

    let vwHeight = CGFloat(200)
    let btnHeight = CGFloat(100)
    let itemHeight = itemView.frame.size.height
    let itemWidth = itemView.frame.size.width
    let carouselX = CGFloat(30)

    let customBtnView = UIView()
    customBtnView.frame = CGRect(x: carouselX, y: itemHeight - vwHeight , width: itemWidth, height: vwHeight)

    customBtnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear


    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: itemWidth, height: btnHeight)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    button.tag = carousel.currentItemIndex
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TutorialsVC.buttonNextAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    customBtnView.addSubview(button)

    carousel.addSubview(customBtnView)

    return itemView

}

func buttonNextAction(sender: UIButton) {

    print("Next==> \(sender.tag)")
    switch sender.tag {
    case 0:
        //do action number 1
        break
    case 1:
        //do action number 2
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The button is not clicking because you have added it as the subview of a `UIImageView`, which does not allow subviews to receive touch events. Instead, you should allocate the passed-in view as a UIView, then add two subviews; A `UIButton` and a `UIImageView`. These subviews can store your button and your card, respectively.