# How to Add a button into iCarousel View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode8

I am using **iCarousel** for showing an image. But I want to add a button into iCarousel. I implemented it but problem is that custom button action does not work, only `didSelectItem` work when I click on the button. here is my code. Please, any one helps me out.

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

NSString *str=[[appController 
    sharedappController].allLibraryImagesArrM objectAtIndex:index];
view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 200.0f)];
((UIImageView *)view).image = [[appController sharedappController].allLibraryImagesArrM objectAtIndex:index];

view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
//[view addSubview:cross];


UIButton *cross = [[UIButton alloc]init];
cross.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.size.width/2+30, view.frame.origin.y+30, 40, 40);
[cross setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cross addTarget:self action:@selector(crossMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cross.png"];
[cross setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[view addSubview:cross];
return view;
}
```

Comment: Refer this ans by @Nick himself.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22145978/my-custom-button-is-not-getting-click-in-icarousel-ios

Comment: You should check frame of your Button. Why its dyanamic??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you enable UserInteraction?

**Enable UserInteraction**

```
[view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: It's Work fine. Thanks